# Gridview Row select and Delete

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, gridview, delete-row

I have a Gridview which shows id and name. I just want to delete the selected row in gridview and in database also by clicking on a button(on click event). There is a single delete button outside the gridview.

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: how do you select the row? using checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
GrdView.Rows.RemoveAt(GrdView.SelectedRows[0].Index);
```

if multiple rows selection enabled then

```
if (GrdView.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow ro in GrdView.SelectedRows)
    {
        try
        {
            GrdView.Rows.Remove(ro);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Not Allowed...");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx to modify @GrantWinney. but that also works fine.

Comment: does it also deletes the data from the database too ?

Comment: How can I remove a row when click the remove button?

Answer (score 0):

In the Submit_Click :

```
for (int i = 0; i < GV.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    GridViewRow row = GV.Rows[i];
    isChecked = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("chkDelItem")).Checked;

    if (isChecked)
    {
        // delete
    }
}
```